# Unable to see new version in itunes connection activity tab

Tags: ios, build, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload a new version of app in to itunes, added a new version like blow image.[image]

I am uploaded with same version of app using application loader and also tried with xcode. app version is 1.0.1 and build is 1.0.1.3. But i am unable to see the version in itunes connect activity tab. Please check the added screen shot.
[image]

It is showing only 1.0 that is previous version of app.

But it is showing in app store version.

[image]

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the app build no and version under the general

Comment: I had a same issue. Didn't get any solution.